# How to fill or shade area between two corresponding points in stacked bar plots in Python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a dataframe `df` which looks as follows:

```
A   B
X   5   7
Y   10  5
```

`df.to_dict()` gives the following:

```
{'A': {'X': 5, 'Y': 10}, 'B': {'X': 7, 'Y': 5}}
```

I have created a stacked bar plot using

```
df.plot(kind = "bar", stacked = True)
```

It look as follows:
[image]

I want to shade the region between A in X and Y bar, and the same for B. The shaded region reflect how the value of A and B has changed between X and Y. It should look something as shown:
[image]

How can I fill areas in between these two stacked bar plots using matplotlib in Python keeping the original structure of bar plot intact?

Comment: I imagine something manually, like extracting the bars' coordinates and plot a `fill_between`

Comment: I tried ```fill_between``` as well. But the area between 2 bars is not exactly a rectangle, but a trapezium. I am not sure how exactly how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using [`fill_between`.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html)

```
ax = df.plot(kind = "bar", stacked = True)
plt.fill_between(x = [ax.patches[0].get_x() + ax.patches[0].get_width(), 
                      ax.patches[1].get_x()], 
                 y1 = 0, 
                 y2 = [ax.patches[0].get_y() + ax.patches[0].get_height(),
                       ax.patches[1].get_y() + ax.patches[1].get_height()], 
                color = ax.patches[0].get_facecolor(), alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(x = [ax.patches[2].get_x() + ax.patches[2].get_width(), 
                      ax.patches[3].get_x()], 
                 y1 = [ax.patches[0].get_y() + ax.patches[0].get_height(),
                       ax.patches[1].get_y() + ax.patches[1].get_height()], 
                 y2 = [ax.patches[2].get_y() + ax.patches[2].get_height(),
                       ax.patches[3].get_y() + ax.patches[3].get_height()], 
                color = ax.patches[2].get_facecolor(), alpha=0.5)
plt.plot()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another fill_between with more general approach:

```
# loop through the bars to get the bottom and top points
bottoms = []
tops = []
for patch in ax.patches:
    x,y = patch.get_xy()
    w,h = patch.get_width(), patch.get_height()
    
    bottoms += [(x,y), (x+w, y)]
    tops += [(x, y+h), (x+w, y+h)]

# convert to numpy for easy slicing
tops = np.array(tops)
bottoms = np.array(bottoms)

# extract the x coordinates
x = np.unique(bottoms[:,0])
num_x = len(x)

# fill between each bottom and top pairs
for i in range(0, len(bottoms), num_x):
    plt.fill_between(x, tops[i:i+num_x, 1], bottoms[i:i+num_x, 1], alpha=0.5)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found an easy way myself using `ax.fill_between()`. For x, I specify [0.25, 0.75]. 0.25 refers to the right edge of bar for X and 0.75 refers to the left edge of bar for Y. The positions in X-axis with ticks for X and Y are 0 and 1 respectively.

For y1 and y2, I specify the y-coordinates of lower and upper edges to be filled in between respectively.

> ```
> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
> ax = df.plot(kind = "bar", stacked = True, ax = ax, color = ["blue","orange"])
>
> ax.fill_between(x =[0.25,0.75], y1 = [0, 0], y2 = [5, 10], color = "blue", alpha = 0.5)
> ax.fill_between(x =[0.25, 0.75], y1 = [5, 10], y2 = [12, 15], color = "orange", alpha = 0.5)
> plt.show()
> ```

I get something as shown:
[image]